# Modeling an unobserved variable

Tags: time-series, estimation, latent-variable, nonparametric

I am trying to parametrically model an unobserved variable $z$. (Does this even make sense?) It has one predictor $x$, which is nonnegative. If the predictor's value is 0, $z$ should be 0. If the predictor's value is greater than 0, it should lie between 0 and 1. If future values of the predictor are less than the average of the recent past values, the predicted variable should be closer to 0. Moreover, the closer $x$ is to 0, the closer $z$ should be to 0. The parameters should be dynamic and reflect recent values of $x$. Learning should be online (i.e. parameters should be adjusted as new values of $x$ are observed.) How can I mathematically model this? What loss function can I use to fit the parameters of the model?

Comment: You may see something similar to what you need at http://statweb.stanford.edu/~owen/courses/306a/threesidedcoin_amstat.pdf though it isn't for time series.  The final models have missing parameters that are hypothesized to exist, but which cannot be measured.